# Inject bean inside AspectJ object before using it

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj

i'm using aspectj aop inside spring boot application , as we know the Aspectj object can be obtain by calling `Aspects.aspectOf(MyAspect.class)` .  There's a dependency `Foo` inside `MyAspect.class` , so i set the field the way below.

```
@Aspectj
public class MyAspect{
   private Foo foo ;

   public void setFoo(Foo foo){
     this.foo = foo;
   }
}

@Bean
public Foo foo(){
   Foo foo = new Foo();
   MyAspectj myAspectj = Aspects.aspectOf(MyAspectj.class);
   myAspectj.setFoo(foo);
   return foo;
}
```

My problems is , the `Foo` bean initializatino is too late , logic in other bean has already start running and initialized the `MyAspectj` already . it turned out `NullPointException` because of the absent of `Foo` .

```
   public void handler(EventMessage eventMessage) {
        JoinPoint var3 = Factory.makeJP(ajc$tjp_0, this, this, eventMessage);
        LoggerAspect var10000 = LoggerAspect.aspectOf();
        Object[] var5 = new Object[]{this, eventMessage, var3};
        var10000.loggerOut((new MessageHandler$AjcClosure3(var5)).linkClosureAndJoinPoint(69648));
    }
```

My question is , how to properly initialize MyAspectj.class , before any code using it ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on

Spring dependsOn will do the trick , every object is managed by spring except `MyAspectj` , so i could use dependsOn on `Bean` that will use `MyAspect` .